# Firefox and Opera not computing background-image

Tags: css, firefox, background-image, opera

### The problem

I just found a very strange issue with `background-images` in Firefox and Opera: the rule simply doesn't get computed.

The rule doesn't get shown in the inspector list, the images in background doesn't get even loaded in network monitors. But everything is ok in the css file being loaded, tough... the rule, the selector, everything just fine.

*The same page works ok in all other browsers, except these two.*

Wonder if anyone had this experience earlier. Thanks.

### Examples

I could manage to reproduce the error in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) as suggested by [Vucko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763929/vucko) and [monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341744/monkey). I got two fiddles: [one working](http://jsfiddle.net/wc5sb/6/) and [one crashing](http://jsfiddle.net/wc5sb/5/). The crashing one is more closer to what I have here in context. Hope it helps.

*PS.: Just note that the crashing one actually works in browsers other than Opera and Firefox.*

Comment: Show us your CSS/HTML.

Comment: Post it to: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Just edited the post with a [relevant example](http://jsfiddle.net/wc5sb/5/). Thanks for helping out.

Comment: As Vucko points out, you have an invalid selector there.  Per spec, that means the whole rule is discarded.  Unfortunately, some browsers don't actually follow the spec...

Comment: Strange thing is that the rule was working in other browsers. Changed and now it works with all of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the last line in your **CSS** code.

`#myprojectname > #page1 > .beginning:after > h2 > div`.

Tested in opera and mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Did you supply a relative URI like in `background-image: url(img/picture.jpg)`? Relative URIs are always resolved with the CSS file as the root.

Means, if you have the following file layout:
    /css/style.css
    /img/picture.jpg
    /index.html

You have to write `background-image: url(../img/picture.jpg)` instead.

Setting the base tag `<base href="/" />` won't help you, since the setting does not transfer.

Comment: Well, actually this is not a relative path issue, as I could reproduce [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc5sb/5/). As I'm using Rails with Compass for CSS, the final generated rule for the sprite is something like: `background: url(/assets/cases/myprojectname-page1-s47cec95689.png) no-repeat;`
Thanks for helping, by the way.